# OpenCV Real time color/form detection

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, object-detection, color-detection

I would like to do a "Real time video detection" of traffic lights (green, yellow, red) of circle and sign (left turn/right turn signs and etc.)

I want to:

- Fix my video recording device(android cellphone) and while taking a video of traffic lights it will calculate green, yellow and red times and stop after some iterations. Main thing is to get at least basic knowledge of this process. Would appreciate if you`ll forward related topics.

  `green - 45 sec`

  `yellow - 4 sec`

  `red - 70 sec`

Comment: first get the range of those colors in HSV color space and then time their occurrence.

Comment: Can you provide more information? This task is quite easy if you are processing a pre-recorded video that has consistent lighting conditions and a fixed camera position. Recording the source video at night would make things even easier. Does the stoplight remain in the same position in every frame of video? Are you trying to analyze several videos, or just one?

Comment: @StephenMeschke, Sure! To be short, I`m doing a project and everything starts with traffic light calculation. It`s **not** a **pre-recorded** video. I would like to do a **real time** detection. My actual problems are:

- I want to get basic elements of doing **real-time** detection with outputs like 


`green - 45 sec`

- I will fix my video recording device in angle position with respect to the traffic lights (I can not fix my cellphone directly on straight view to Traffic light)

- How to make my video recording device collaborate with my laptop in real-time

Comment: @NazarTarlanli, I see. This is a really interesting problem! If you are willing to spend some time collecting data (video of traffic lights), and upload it to a site like Kaggle, it is possible that someone will solve this problem for you. I would love to work on it. A word of caution; I created [a small pedestrian dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/smeschke/pedestrian-dataset/home) and almost got hit by a car. It's hard to focus on collecting data and watch out for cars at the same time!